# Pspice Common Emitter Schematic Missing Values

Tags: transistors, bjt, pspice, common-emitter

I am doing some homework at my university, and PSpice keeps saying that there are some missing values. I can't seem to find a solution in my books. Here is the schematic:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert in PSpice, but the following lines seem to spell it out:

```
R_R2         0 2  4,9k  
------------------------$  
ERROR -- Missing value
```

I take it you are from a country where the comma (`,`) is used as a [decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark). PSpice is likely expecting a period (`.`) as the decimal mark. Change the value of `R_R2` to `4.9k`, that should sort it out.

As I understand it, because SPICE uses a comma to separate parameters or other tokens in many contexts, a period/dot must be used as a decimal mark to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Yes - uint128_t is correct. And - more than that, are you aware that there is no input signal (Vin=0)?

Comment: Yeah pretty dumb mistake made by me.Thank you very much.As for the input signal thats the value i recieved from my teacher and its working fine now even without it.

Comment: @LvW I suspect that OP is doing AC analysis or something similar, and therefore the simulator ignores that particular parameter.

Comment: AC analysis without any ac source? Not very probable.

Comment: @LvW I think Vin is the AC source, and that the AC amplitude of that source is hidden on the schematic. I don't know PSpice, but that's what LTSpice does.

Comment: According to the net list: Vin=0V.