# missing value error in orcad pspice

Tags: digital-logic, analog

I am new to Orcad PSPICE simulation. When I try to simulate the schematic in PSPICE, I got the missing value error (shown below). What do I do?

```
*Analysis directives: 
.TRAN  0 1000ns 0 
.OPTIONS ADVCONV
.PROBE64 V(alias(*)) I(alias(*)) W(alias(*)) D(alias(*)) NOISE(alias(*)) 
.INC "..\SCHEMATIC1.net" 

**** INCLUDING SCHEMATIC1.net ****
* source PROJECT EX1
R_R99         N3430589 I_INVT+ 22E
R_R97         DC_LINK- N3430675 10E
R_R96         N3430573 ISO_5V1 10E
R_R98         N3430585 P3.3V 10E
R_R100         N3430593 I_INVT- 22E
R_R95         IINVT N3430581 10E
R_R101         N3431565 N3431092 R
----------------------------------$
ERROR(ORPSIM-16387): Missing value
V_V1         IINVT DGP 25v
V_V2         DC_LINK- N3431092 25V
V_V3         N3431370 0  
+PULSE 0 5 0 1ps 1ps 1s 2s

**** RESUMING "HVLS EX PRO SIM.cir" ****
.END
```

Comment: See if this helps [PSPICE missing value](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/411389/errororpsim-16492). In your case the error may be in the line `R_R101         N3431565 N3431092 R`. The line ends with `R`. But all other resistor lines end with a number.

Comment: [Related](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/223967/238590)

Answer (score 0):

`R_R101         N3431565 N3431092 R`

The two linked answers [1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/411405/238590) and [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/223967/238590) indicate that PSPICE did not find a number where it expected a number. In this case, the value of the resistor `R_R101` is given as `R`. It should be changed to a number (like the resistors above it). If you are using a GUI, you can change by double clicking on the resistor `R_R101`.

I found both previous answers by web-searching `ERROR(ORPSIM-16387): Missing value`.